# Phased array receiver circular polarization

Tags: rf, antenna-array, beamforming

In a phased array system, what will have to change in a receiver's architecture if it needs to work for both linear and circular polarization?

I saw in one article it is said "Supports automatic circular polarization control by embedding 0o/90o phase controllable phase shifters" source:(http://www.satixfy.com/beat/)

Can anyone please explain me why they used the phase shifter?

Answer (score 0):

Nothing systematic. The array elements need to be able to pick up the circular polarization, but the antenna gain comes from the phase difference, which doesn't care about polarization.

Comment: I am sorry but I could not get the idea why they needed the phase shifter and mentioned it that it is for circular polarization, Can u please elaborate a little, may be it is a basic concept but i am really struggling to grasp it

Comment: The phase shifting is for the two linear polarizations of the *individual* antennas. You can use two cross-polarized linear antennas with the same phase center, and link them with a phase shift and get a circularly polarized antenna. That applies to the individual antennas, but has nothing to do with the fact you might be using these antennas in an array.